# How do I know whether a signed In user is a newly created user or existing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In firebase you esesentially don't need to use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` to create a user (nor it is possible without login into another account)
but you can use `signInWithCredential()` all cases ie to create as well as signin.
So given that I am using `signInWithCredential()` for both new and existing user case, how do I differentiate the two.

Here in their [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/940ac4da5dd6cb212234abbc05d0fd54044fba52/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/SignInActivity.java#L121) writeNewUser() is being call for all onAuthSuccess cases not just for new users.

How to figure out whether the signedin user is new user or existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell existing and new users from the AuthResult returned in `signInWithCredential`:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult

It provides a getter: `getAdditionalUserInfo()` which returns a `AdditionalUserInfo` which provides `isNewUser()` to tell if a user is new or existing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#isNewUser()

Comment: Thanks, it seems they have just added it in `11.6.0` , it wasn't there in `11.2.0` that I was using.